# Unable to generate iOS certificate

Tags: ios, certificate

I have three iOS production certificates and I one to create a new one for a new app I'm building. However, when I go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateCreate.action the option of "App Store and Ad Hoc" for Production environment is grayed out.

Anyone else experiencing this - or know the reason?

Comment: do you have many certificates already?

Comment: as I remember you can have only one distribution certificate, and any amount certificates for developing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit to the number of production certificates that can be created from an account. So, to create new ones in your account, you will have to revoke any of the existing ones.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that I've been confusing some terms. 1 certificate for more profiles. I tried to have 1 profile for each certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Please revoke the previous certificate from apple developer account and create new one. Also you can do one thing export certificate from keychain and install in your mac and create new appId from developer account and re-use that certificate so that no need to revoke the previous certificate.